# notificationTokenNotUpdatedOnServer - Worklight

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I have set up **module_07_04_iOSNativePush** iOS project with **NativeAPIForIOSPush** as a server component. I have updated .p12 file in work light project. and changed application-descriptor.xml to following:

```
<nativeIOSApp xmlns="http://www.worklight.com/native-ios-descriptor" bundleId="com.company.pushtest" id="Module_07_04_nativeAPIForiOSPush" platformVersion="6.0.0" securityTest="PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest" version="1.0">
<displayName>Module_07_04_nativeAPIForiOSPush</displayName>
<description>Module_07_04_nativeAPIForiOSPush</description>
<pushSender password="1234567890"/>
</nativeIOSApp>
```

Now, when I run iOS project with updated IP in worklight.plist (I am testing on local machine), following Error is seen in XCode Log:(Date time and app name is removed for better visibility)

```
My token from APNS : <88da2d33 d877481f 0a7abb70 13319b03 761d0d15 a72b7825 6a5d31e3 0d95da25>
My token from APNS : <88da2d33 d877481f 0a7abb70 13319b03 761d0d15 a72b7825 6a5d31e3 0d95da25>
[ERROR] Worklight: -[WLRequest requestFailed:]:324::statusCode
[ERROR] Worklight: -[WLClient onInitRequestFailure:userInfo:]:586::
notificationTokenNotUpdatedOnServer
```

Anyone know about this issue. What I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I assume that's not the actual password of your p12 certificate, right...?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if **wlServerContext** and **application id** is correct.
*wlServerContext* should be the *Worklight Application name* and *application id* should be the *app name*